# Implementing a custom SessionIDManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to implement a custom SessionIDManager very similar [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.validate.aspx).

I'm putting this in the web.config similar to how they showed in the example:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="SessionID"
         type="ProjectName.WebUI.Models.CustomSessionIDManager" />
  </httpModules>
  // --snip--
</system.web>
```

However when attempting to load the website I am getting the configuration error:

> ProjectName.WebUI.Models.CustomSessionIDManager does not implement IHttpModule.

If I remove that part of the web.config, the website loads, but the overridden part of the custom SessionIDManager does not get run.

How do I properly tell the web.config to use my custom SessionIDManager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact I think there's a bug in the documentation. You don't need to add it to the `<httpModules>` section but to the `<sessionState>` section as [illustrated here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.createsessionid.aspx):

```
<sessionState
    Mode="InProc"
    stateConnectionString="tcp=127.0.0.1:42424"
    stateNetworkTimeout="10"
    sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Integrated Security=SSPI"
    sqlCommandTimeout="30"
    customProvider=""
    cookieless="false"
    regenerateExpiredSessionId="false"
    timeout="20"
    sessionIDManagerType="Your.ID.Manager.Type, CustomAssemblyNameInBinFolder"
/>
```