# How to Generate a new Session ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, sessionid

**Is it possible to generate a new ID for the session using ASP.NET?**

I want it to change when someone logs in to my website just before I set their initial session variables.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do this using the [SessionIdManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx) class:

```
SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();

string newID = manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
bool redirected = false;
bool isAdded = false;
manager.SaveSessionID(Context, newID, out redirected, out isAdded);
```

[Code sample is from [Anas Ghanem's article]](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/12/16/programmatically-changing-the-session-id.aspx)

Comment: Yes, with above code I get new sessionId every time but this causes other problem ie. it clears session variable every time page loads even when I have put above code in if (!IsPostBack){}

Comment: @user1650891 you should start a new question

Comment: Here is the link to my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606885/session-saved-in-handler-cannot-be-accessed-in-aspx-file/)

Comment: "This method is not intended to be called from application code." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.savesessionid(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: My `SessionID` is not updating. `Context.Session.SessionID` displays the same values.

Comment: new sessionid generated and added to ASP.NET_SessionId but then other session values become null

Answer (score 5):

you can use

[**`SessionIDManager.CreateSessionID Method :`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.createsessionid.aspx) returns a unique session identifier that is a randomly generated number encoded into a 24-character string.

Code

```
SessionIDManager Manager = new SessionIDManager(); 
string NewID = Manager.CreateSessionID(Context); 
string OldID = Context.Session.SessionID;
bool redirected = false;
bool IsAdded = false;
Manager.SaveSessionID(Context, NewID,out redirected, out IsAdded);
```

Here you can find full detail about hsi : [Changing the session ID programmatically.](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/12/16/programmatically-changing-the-session-id.aspx)

Comment: what is context object here in terms of mvc action method?

Answer (score 4):

yes it is possible to generate new ID for the session.
below is one example

```
SessionState.SessionIDManager Manager = new SessionState.SessionIDManager(); 
string NewID = Manager.CreateSessionID(Context); 
string OldID = Context.Session.SessionID; 

bool IsAdded = false; 
Manager.SaveSessionID(Context, NewID, false, IsAdded); 

Response.Write("Old SessionId Is : " + OldID); 
if (IsAdded) { 
    Response.Write("&lt;br/> New Session ID Is : " + NewID); 
} 
else { 
    Response.Write("&lt;br/> Session Id did not saved : "); 
}
```

Comment: new sessionid generated and added to ASP.NET_SessionId but then other session values become null

Answer (score 3):

The ASP.Net session management infrastructure does not expose a supported way to change your session id during the handling of a request.  If writing supported code is important to you, there are several things to be aware of with the accepted answer.

- Both `CreateSessionID` and `SaveSessionID` are [marked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.savesessionid(v=vs.110).aspx) "This method is not intended to be called from application code".
- The SessionID provider is a pluggable type (see e.g. [Implementing a custom SessionIDManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612310/implementing-a-custom-sessionidmanager)), so at the very least you would need to instantiate the correct type.
- The session state attached to the `HttpContext` will remain associated with the initial session id, so anything you put in the session state bag will appear to be lost.  Since there isn't anything you can do with the session once you've changed your id, it's kind of pointless to change your id this way.

Unfortunately, there isn't a supported way to do this without a round-trip.  What you need to do is to wipe the session state cookie when you generate the login form.  When the user submits the form back, the framework will call into the `SessionIDManager` to generate a new one.  Wiping the session cookie correctly is slightly more complicated than most of the code samples show.  The cookie name is another parameter configurable in the web.config.  You need to read it from the configuration by accessing the property:

```
((System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState")).CookieName
```

The session id cookie is not scoped to the application, so if there are two applications installed on the same server it's often desirable to have them use different cookie names, so this is required more commonly than you might think.

Comment: new sessionid generated and added to ASP.NET_SessionId but then other session values become null

Comment: @BalasubramanianRamamoorthi If I understand your comment, this is addressed in my third bullet point. It's not that anything becomes null, it's that the old data was associated with the old session id. The crux is that you are not changing the sessionid for your session, you are making a new id that will link with a new empty session.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is security related?  Will a `Session.Clear()` or `Session.Abandon()` work for you?  [This is a good SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470445/what-is-the-difference-between-session-abandon-and-session-clear) related to those methods.

Otherwise, it is difficult because the ASP.NET session cookie is already on the user's browser.  You might not have confidence that the session was truly changed.